# MySQL displaying results from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have set up a many-to-many relationship db with 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLES Films (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),    
Title VARCHAR(255)),  

CREATE TABLE Moods (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
mood_name VARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE Films_Moods (
film_id INT NOT NULL,  
mood_id INT NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (film_id, mood_id),  
FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (mood_id) REFERENCES Moods(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE)";
```

So there might be a film with 2 or more moods. Let them be `$mood1` and `$mood2`.

I want to display the selected film in a table as a single row, for example in the following way:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Mood(s)</th>
</tr>
```

and the PHP code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Moods'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

The question is: how to obtain `$row['Moods']` that would somehow combine two rows:
film_1 moodName_1
film_1 moodName_2

Or is there an alternative approach to what I am trying to achieve?

**EDIT**

Actually Im using tables Genres and Ambiences similarly to Moods and Im trying to do a search with specific Genres and Ambiences:

```
"SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences FROM Films AS f 
        INNER JOIN Films_Genres AS fg ON f.id = fg.film_id
        INNER JOIN Genres AS g  ON g.id = fg.genre_id
        INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id           
        INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
        WHERE g.Name LIKE '$genre' AND (a.ambienceName LIKE '$ambience1' OR a.ambienceName LIKE '$ambience2')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title,GROUP_CONCAT(mood_name SEPARATOR ' ') AS moods
FROM films 
JOIN films_moods ON films.id=films_moods.film_id
JOIN moods ON films_moods.mood_id=moods.id
GROUP BY title
```

You can fiddle with this by going to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6dd3/14/0 - I also fixed a couple of typos in your schema.

Comment: Okay, this is useful, however when I put it into a more complicated query, all the results appear in one row..
Actually Im using Genres and Ambiences similarly to Moods:`
    "SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences   FROM Films AS f 
   INNER JOIN Films_Genres AS fg ON f.id = fg.film_id
   INNER JOIN Genres AS g  ON g.id = fg.genre_id
   INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa ON f.id = fa.film_id   
   INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
   WHERE g.Name LIKE '$genre' AND (a.ambienceName LIKE '$ambience1' OR a.ambienceName LIKE '$ambience2')"`

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with your other query. If I were you, I'd go to sqlfiddle, put in your schema, including some sample data, and the query that doesn't work, and post a new question. Oh, and tick my answer as correct ;)

Comment: And: use example genres, instead of $genre, AND NEVER USE variables in a SQL statement, you are asking for sql injection attacks! Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: whoa thanks for the warning! I will try the sql fiddle and let you know in a sec ;) Thanks for help @AMADANON